# Validating integer Input using a Mask (Asp .NET MVC 3.0) 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, maskedinput

My Model :

```
public virtual int? NumberTest { get; set; }
```

My View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberTest)
<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumberTest)
```

I'm using [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), so I have in my View :

```
$("#NumberTest").mask("99999-999");
```

My Html generated :

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NumberTest must be a number." id="NumberTest" name="NumberTest" type="text" value="" />
```

So it automatically generated a number validation on my Integer input... And I'm using a mask with non-integer char to format number....

This validatior is always called when I fill the input ... How can I fix that?

Comment: Looks like the '-' in the mask is throwing your validator.

Comment: Yes... So, the only way to fix that is not using any separator?

Comment: In my case, I have a `decimal` property, and my mask is `£ 99999` and the pound sign throws the default front-end validation for MVC. Is there no easy way over this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was set the data type to string so it would work with maskedinput, but then in a custom model binder, I stripped out all the non-numeric characters so it could save to the database as an int.  You still get both client-side and server-side protection because the user is prevented from entering non-numeric characters by maskedinput client-side and potentially bad characters are filtered out server-side.

Here's the custom model binder code:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (value != null && propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            // always trim strings to clean up database padding
            value = ((string)value).Trim();

            if ((string)value == string.Empty)
            {
                value = null;
            }
            else if ((propertyDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(PhoneNumberAttribute)] != null
                || propertyDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(ZipCodeAttribute)] != null
                || propertyDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(SocialSecurityNumberAttribute)] != null)
                && bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name) != null
                && bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name).AttemptedValue != null)
            {
                value =
                    Regex.Replace(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name).AttemptedValue,
                                  "[^0-9]", "");
            }
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

The custom attributes are just empty Attributes:

```
public class ZipCodeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

In the view model, just mark your field like this:

```
[ZipCode]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Here's how to do the [whole thing with maskedinput, editor templates and unobtrusive validation](http://robertcorvus.com/automatically-validate-and-format-data-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/).